# Android fragment crash after returning back to application

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, crash, minimize

I am student and i am working on Android plugin, which uses lifecycle observer, so my plugin just **overlaying the app** in which is implemented. I have to display some flow - set of fragments - to detect if user is suitable for our work.

I have a problem, when user **minimize app** when in flow (displaying some fragment), **after returning** to app fragment display just for a second and then **crash without error message**. I really looking for solution on internet, also debugging my plugin, no reason why crashes. I discovered, that onCreate, onStart or onResume of activity that holds fragments were not called when going back to app. Also none of fragment callback methods were called.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you add exception log?

Comment: There is no exception log, fragment just display for a second and then "hide" or what.